# Aquamacs Highlighting when Selecting Text

Tags: aquamacs

I've sadly been struggling with this for a while, but whenever I select text with my mouse in Aquamacs, it automatically highlights the end of the region and will continue to highlight anything typed after it, until I select somewhere else.

[image: Selecting Text]
[image: After]

Kinda a minor, but very annoying issue...

Answer (score 1):

possibly due to stuck Option/Alt (Meta) key

perhaps related problem that I have, is difficulty in copying region using <kbd>M-w</kbd>. if I hold Meta by itself for too long before hitting <kbd>w</kbd>, it goes into highlight mode, and doesn't "copy" the text..

Comment: Thanks, I have had the problem that text gets inexplicably highlighted and not copied when I attempt to M-w it, and have been struggling to find out what happens. It turns out that if meta is pressed when I select something with the mouse, the selected area becomes "secondary selection", which is what the yellow means.